# Calculating how many different items to use

Tags: javascript, html

A user inputs an amount of water they need, I need to calculate which bottles to use, either 10l bottles or 20l bottles. So if they ask for 67l, the script pops up with 3x20l and 1x10l

I have tried the following 2 solutions

```
    var resinAm = rsize*1.1*2.5
    var resTin = '';
        if(resinAm<10){
            resTin = 1;
        } else {
            resTin = resinAm/20;
            resTin = Math.ceil(resTin);
        }
```

and this

```
    var resAm = resinAm;
    var resAm10 = (resAm/10)+0.001;
    var resAm20 = (resAm/20)*2;
    if(resAm10>resAm20){
        resTin10 = 1;
        resTin20 = Math.floor(resAm/20);
    } else {
        resTin20 = Math.ceil(resAm/20);
    }
```

I have also tried using modulo, but it always comes out with an extra 20l bottle, 70.5l came out as 5x20l and 1x10l

How do I fix this

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code as text, rather than as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code at: https://jsfiddle.net/a4k2cyoy/2/

```
var resAm = 70.5;

var resAm20 = parseInt(resAm / 20);
var resAm10 = 0;

if(resAm % 20 > 10) {
    resAm20++;
}

if(resAm % 20 <= 10 && resAm > 0) {
    resAm10++;
}

alert(resAm + " will go into " + resAm20 + " x 20 bottles and " + resAm10 + " x 10 bottles");
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this

```
var value = 67;
var tenLBottles = Math.ceil(value % 20 /10);
var twentyLBottles = (value - value%20)/20
```

Comment: No. Try with 79, it fails

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, fill bottles array with what you want

```js
var water = 67;
var bottles = [20, 10, 3]; // bottles in desc order
var currentBottleIndex = 0

while(water > 0 && currentBottleIndex < bottles.length) {
  console.log(Math.floor(water / bottles[currentBottleIndex]) + ' bottles of ' + bottles[currentBottleIndex])
  water = water % bottles[currentBottleIndex]
  currentBottleIndex ++;
}
console.log('rest water', water)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a math quesion, put it simple,you can realize it this way:

```
    var bottles=[20,10];

function choose_bottle(water) {
    var bottle1_num,bottle2_num;
    if(water<=10) {
        return "1*"+bottles[1];
    }
    else if(water>10&&water<=20) {
        return "1*"+bottles[0];
     }
    else {
        bottle1_num = Math.floor(water/bottles[0]);
        bottle2_num = Math.ceil((water -bottle1_num*bottles[0])/bottles[1]);
        return bottle1_num+"*"+bottles[0]+" "+bottle2_num+"*"+bottles[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: 70.5 returns: "3*20 2*10". Why not just "4 * 20" instead of 5 bottles?

Comment: @SmartDev i have thought about that, but that is not what the result of the guy who brings up this question wants

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job:

```
var amount = 67;
var bottle20 = Math.floor(amount / 20);
var bottle10 = Math.ceil((amount - bottle20 * 20) / 10);
```